# How to use block-grid classes

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Everything has been working great: grids, media queries, text visibility, and all that other good stuff.

I tried to use block grids for my social media image links and found that it wasn't working at all. I scoured through the foundation files I included in my project and `block-grid` classes are not defined anywhere. I'm curious what I'm missing. Is there a separate file that I need to include into my project to use `block-grid`'s?

[Foundation block grid documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/block_grid.html)

Scripts and stylesheets included in my project:

```
<!-- Within Head tag -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/terminal/jquery.terminal-0.9.2.css" />

<!-- At End of Body tag -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/terminal/js/jquery.terminal-0.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/terminal/js/jquery.mousewheel-min.js"></script>
```

An example of what I tried doing:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/blogger.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/email.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/github.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/googleplus.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/linkedin.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/stackoverflow.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-icon" src="./img/twitter.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

The result of the above code is just a normal unordered list, each image has a bullet on a separate line.

Also, `img-icon` class doesn't overwrite anything. Removing this class doesn't make `block-grid` work.

Edit: Just to note, I downloaded foundation 6 via their website from the [website section](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html). You can see what files I included in my project by looking at my script and stylesheet tags above.

Edit 2: `foundation.css` (added to jsfiddle because of size): [foundation.css file contents](https://jsfiddle.net/vwk52zs9/)

Comment: Please add the contents of your `foundation.scss` file to the question so we can see what components you are importing and how you are importing them. Also, there are 4 different "editions" of Foundation you can download from that link you provided so you need to specify which one you are using.

Comment: Hey @ColinMarshall , I downloaded foundation 6 from their website section via their link provided. From the download, received `foundation.css` and the minified version. No changes were made to these files. I will include contents soon, but should be the default from their website

Comment: The download link on that page takes you to a page with 4 different download links (for the different editions) so that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @ColinMarshall Ah oops sorry didn't see that. I've included what I have in my `foundation.css` file in a jsfiddle. Link is in the edit at bottom :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You linked to the Foundation 5 block-grid docs but you are using Foundation 6. In Foundation 6, the block-grid was combined with the regular grid.

> The block grid from Foundation 5 has been merged into the main grid. Add a class of the format [size]-up-[n] to change the size of all columns within the row. By default, the max number of columns you can use with block grid are 6.

Source: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids

Example:

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-4">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! This works great! Thanks for all your help @ColinMarshall

Answer (score 0):

For foundation 6 use that structure.
Remember, de default max columns is 6.

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-4">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```